# how to select data from the table which have default key word as a table name

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am migrating MSSQL based application to MYSQL and i don't know why but the old developer named table as a 'group' which is a keyword.I tried to run query

```
SELECT [group] From [groups] where ID !='b0000000-1111-1111-1111-11111111111b' and ID !='e0000000-1111-1111-1111-11111111111e';
```

and also

```
SELECT group From groups where ID !='b0000000-1111-1111-1111-11111111111b' and ID !='e0000000-1111-1111-1111-11111111111e';
```

but i am getting an error.

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[group]
```

any suggestions?

Comment: use alias for the group column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

` solved the problem

```
SELECT `group` From `groups` where ID !='b0000000-1111-1111-1111-11111111111b' and             ID !='e0000000-1111-1111-1111-11111111111e';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backquote (`)

```
SELECT `group` FROM groups 
WHERE ID !='b0000000-1111-1111-1111-11111111111b' 
AND ID !='e0000000-1111-1111-1111-11111111111e';
```